# Speeding Up Table Queries In SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ssis

I was told that there is a way to do this but I have no idea.  I am hoping that someone more educated than I can help me understand the answer...

There is a table that has been imported from an external source via SSIS.  The destination in SSIS needs to be updated frequently from the external source.  The users are complaining about performance problems in their queries.

How would you update this destination in SSIS to achieve these goals?

Anyone have a clue?  I'm "dry"...

Comment: Sounds more like you need some indexing on the destination table, rather than an SSIS problem (unless SSIS is actually creating the table rather than just updating the data in the table)

Comment: There's a lot of investigation you could do to to simply complete the process of writing a question that actually has some information in it. For example: do these performance issues occur during SSIS execution? How often is the table updated? How long does it take? How many rows does the table have and how many rows are usually loaded each time the process runs? Does the table have indexes? Are indexes loaded/dropped in the load process? How long have the performance issues been occurring? The simple answer is "create some indexes"

Answer (score 1):

If your users are complaining about performance then it is not an SSIS issue.  You need to look at what queries are running against the table. Make sure your table has a primary key and appropriate filters based on the columns used to sort and filter the data.

Can you give us a listing of the table definition?

Answer (score 0):

i'll give u some advice then maybe can improve your ssis performance

- **Use SQL statement** rather than **instant dropdown interface** when you import data from db to your SSIS (using SQL Statement u can **import**, **filter**, **Convert**, and **Sort** at once)
- **Import** & **Filter** only **Column** you needed in SSIS
- Some reference say, you can customize your default buffer settings (**DefaultBufferSize** & **DefaultBufferMaxRows**). this way will improve your bandwidth data process.